# How to have an embedded image in the footer of the last page of a MS Word document?

Tags: images, microsoft-word-2013, footers

I want to display an image in the footer of the last page only of a Word 2013 document.

The document is to be used as a mail merge template in a server-hosted CRM package (Sage CRM).  For this reason, I believe the image will need to be embedded in the document, so I won't be able to use "INCLUDEPICTURE" in a a formula field.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I put a field

```
{ if { page } = { numpages } "" }
```

into the footer of a document, and then inserted a picture between the quotes by this method:

- I went to the "Insert" tab and clicked on "Pictures".
- Navigated to an image file and selected one.

To verify that this works, I saved the document and closed it, shredded the .jpg file (i.e., secure delete), reopened the Word document, and the image was still there (this also verifies that the image is actually embedded, not just a link).

Comment: When you say you inserted a picture, do you mean a link to a picture, or pasted an image?

Comment: I went to the "Insert" tab, clicked on "Pictures", and navigated to an image file.  Then I saved the document and closed it, shredded the .jpg file (i.e., secure delete), and reopened the Word document, and the image was still there, so I guess I really embedded it, and didn't just insert a link.